# Largest range of consecutive integers that can be formed

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Using a subset of a choice with 10 pieces from $\{1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100\}$, what's the largest range of consecutive integer values that can be produced (note that $0$ isn't counted)?

For example, I could take ten ones to get a range of $1$ to $10$, which would give me an answer of $10 - 1 = 9$. I can't seem to do any better than $9$. Can someone please help me with this problem? I don't think that ten ones is the answer because it seems too simple.

Comment: By "produced" do you mean only by addition? I'm only guessing this because the numbers look like Euro coin sizes. And can you really do no better than 9 since it is rather obvious that you can easily make a larger range than that with fewer coins.

Comment: Yes. Only by addition. You can choose some subset of your ten values and add them.

Comment: @Jaap These are also the denominations of U.S. currency.

Comment: @DanielMathias Oh right, US bills rather than coins.

Comment: Can you reuse items from the set? Like 2+2?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure this is the maximum, but without proof:

> Take as your multiset $\{1,2,2,5,10,20,20,50,100,100\}$. This gets you all the integers between 1 and 310.

Comment: Yes, this is optimal if the range must start with 1.

Comment: @RobPratt Can you do better if not?

Comment: @PaulPanzer I have now checked each starting point up through 1000, and you cannot do better.  Because 1001 is not representable, this search suffices.

Answer (score 0):

1~9: at most 3 pieces. 8, 9 need 3.

10~90: at most 3 pieces. 80, 90 need 3.

so you can get from 1 to 499 without a problem.
because at most 4 x 100, 3 for 10~90, and 3 for 1~9.

But above 500, you need 5 x 100. you have 5 left for the rest.
with 5, you can get from 1 to 87.
so the range of the consecutive number is 1 ~ 587. You can't get 588 because 80 needs 3, 8 needs 3.

Edit: As people suggested in the comments, this method doesn't use a fixed set of pieces. Instead, it gets a separate set for each number.

Comment: But e.g. 8 would be 5 + 2 + 1 while 9 would be 5 + 2 + 2, so you need two 2s, because you can't reuse them. -> 4 pieces for 1-9, 4 pieces for 10-90, and 2x100. (already in Jeremy's answer)

Comment: @LukasRotter Would you explain why you need 4 pieces for 9? what do you mean by can't reuse them?

Comment: From OP's comment: "You can choose some subset of your ten values and add them" -> no reuse of numbers

Comment: @bobble I think you can have duplicates, otherwise, how can you get 10 pieces of 7 types of currencies without duplications?

Comment: The ten numbers that you choose for your set can be duplicates. But when you are taking numbers from the set, you cannot take the same number twice. Some numbers, when removed, may duplicate each other, but you cannot choose a number more often than it appears in your initial 10-number set.

Comment: You cannot get values 1-9 with 3 coins.  There are 9 values and only 8 subsets.  You seem to assume you can pick 10 coins freely for each number.  But the question is to pick 10 coins first and then do a maximum of numbers with subsets of these 10.